# Localization and how to handle web content on an iOS app

Tags: ios, web-services, ios7, localization

Let's say if I have some content coming from a web service that's in English (en-US). Now, to go with localization what's the best way to localize this content?

I kind was leaning towards having the web service spit out localized content but that wouldn't be ideal on a hindsight.

Anyone knows what's the best way to get these contents localized and out to an iOS app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get current locale:

```
NSString * language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
```

When loading you web content, pass the locale identifier to your request. On server side generate localized response based on the identifier.

Comment: I kinda sensed that but wanted to see if people do any way different or if there are clever ways to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the web service to supply the localized content. If it is troublesome to populate localized data then you should probably use some translation service
Try google translate API for this purpose
https://developers.google.com/translate/

Comment: That was my thought as well but using Google Translate wouldn't cut for full sentences. I might have to translate it with translators and such. But thanks.